# Bind models using JSON body, without [FromBody]

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, model-binding

I'm using ASP.NET Core, and having to specify `[FromBody]` to get my models bound, which is a PITA.

I'm making POST requests, sending JSON data in the request body, and with the `Content-Type` header set to `application/json`.

I'm wondering if there is some way to globally configure that models should be bound from the request body when it contains JSON?

Comment: Does your Controller act like an API Controller (like RESTfull)?

Comment: For MVC, we usually send request by `Form`, its default model provider is from form, will you develop with ApiController or your controller default provider is json? If so, you could decode your controller with `[ApiController]` which will bind data from json body. But for this way, if you need to bind from form, you need to add `[FromForm].`

Comment: @Hameed @Tao this is for an MVC app that has some POST endpoints that accept JSON. The same controllers have methods that accept normal GET requests, as well as some POST endpoints that use the more "standard" form encoding (so using `ApiController` probably isn't an option, as it would mess with the other endpoints)